# How do I compare two nested maps excluding certain keys

Tags: java

I have two nested Hashmaps which have the following structure

```
key1: {
 key2: {
    bad_key: {}
}
}
```

How do I compare two hashmaps, omitting only certain nested keys?

One solution is to traverse through both maps(You can flatten your map, i.e. include folded keys into main map), remove nested keys and do a

```
Map1.equals(Map2)
```

Are there any better solutions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Maps` from [Guava: Google Core Libraries For Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/19.0)

```
MapDifference<Integer, Student> mapDifference = Maps.difference(map1, map2);
```

If you don't want to use external library, I would just do something like this:

```
List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three'");


for(String key: keys){
    if(!left.get(key).equals(right.get(key))){
       //do something with difference
    }
};
```